# How to import external javascript library into Bokeh generated html

Tags: javascript, bokeh, bokehjs

I would like to make use of a javascript library (specifically [this one](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix/blob/master/dist/gl-matrix.js)) in my Bokeh javascript callback. How can I specify importing of this javascript library such that the library is accessible from Bokeh's js callback functions?

The examples at:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html

mainly talk about creating a custom Bokeh Model. I am not particularly interested in creating a new Model, just want to use the library functions in a callback to modify the data that is plotted.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways:

- Server app
- Standalone HTML app

Here is how:

> Server app:

You can create a Bokeh server directory structure.

1. create a directory called myapp
2. name your Python script main.py and put it there
3. create a subdirectory there called templates
4. create index.html, main.js and optional styles.css files and put them in templates subdirectory
5. open terminal, navigate to directory one level higher than `myapp` directory and start your app with this command: `bokeh serve --show myapp`

The following example works for Bokeh v1.0.4.

Directory structure:

```
myapp
   |
   +---main.py
   +---templates
        +---index.html
        +---main.js
        +---styles.css
```

main.py

```
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from bokeh.models import Button, CustomJS

button = Button(label = 'Click Me')
button.callback = CustomJS(code = """ alert($) """)

curdoc().add_root(button)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {{ bokeh_css }}
    {{ bokeh_js }}
    <style>
    {% include 'styles.css' %}
    </style>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
    {% include 'main.js' %}
    </script>
    {{ plot_div|indent(8) }}
    {{ plot_script|indent(8) }}
  </body>
</html>
```

Please note that this way you can include local, but also **remote** JS libraries or style sheets.

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('jQuery succesfully loaded !') 
});
```

styles.css

```
body { background: #111122; }
```

> Standalone HTML app:

```
import os
from bokeh.io import save
from bokeh.models import Slider
from bokeh.util.browser import view

template = """
{% block postamble %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var slider = Bokeh.documents[0].get_model_by_name('my_slider')
            alert('slider value: ' + slider.value)
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %} """

slider = Slider(start=0, end=10, value=5, name='my_slider')

save(slider, template=template)
view(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.basename(__file__)).replace('.py', ".html")
```